# Does a tilt-invariant point exist for this problem?

Tags: geometry, vectors

This is a geometric question I'm struggling to get a definitive answer for.
It *should* be simple, I think, but to my shame I nevertheless need some help.
Also, I need to convince a non-mathematician of the result ;c)

### Pre-text

Imagine a flat plane of finite size (a sheet of paper, if you will) lying flat in a 3D space aligned with X & Y as shown in the figure below.

On this paper, take a small rectangle area (red) at any location.

I now tilt the paper around a tilt axis which is parallel to X and goes through the centre of red rectangle.

What I'm seeking is a second rectangle area (green) in a distance of the red one which has to be chosen such, that for every tilt-angle the centre of the green and the centre of the red area have the same z-coordinate, i.e. remain at same height.

The solution is obvious: Choose an area along the tilt-axis as in the following image:

[image]

### The Question

Now image a starting situation in which the blue sheet of paper is pre-titled, i.e. it has been tilted by an arbitrary amount around an arbitrary tilt axis lying in the XY plane (which is not parallel to X).

Again, an arbitrary red area on the plane is thought, and a tilt-axis parallel to X and going through the centre of the red area is chosen:

[image]

> Is it still possible to find a green area (on the plane) such that the centre of green and red area have the same z-coordinated regardless of the tilt-angle I'm choosing?

*I believe the answer to be **no** but would need a formal 'proof' for that.* (unless I'm wrong.)

And related: If I *do* choose an arbitrary green area (specified as offset in the plane), how do I compute the difference of in Z as a function of alpha?

### Practical background

> I feel that I should shed a bit of light on the practical relevance of that question - just in case I've formulated it badly. If you consider this 'fluff', please just skip.

The context of the problem is Transmission Electron Microscopy and Tomography. In this technique, one always acquires images "in transmission" along Z, so that one always sees a projection image and "X/Y" expresses the image coordinate system but not the coordinate system of the real sample.

Normally, the sample lies "flat" in x & y like in situation one. For tomography, tilt-series (with alpha) are acquired, and the involved routines often perform measurements to track mechanical instabilities (the focus along z is adjusted.) To not 'destroy' the area of interest (red) these measurements are generally done "close-by" (green) and one can define the area as "shift" from the red area in X & Y (i.e. in the projected coordinate system).
(The tilt axis is ensured to go through the centre of the red area by adjusting the system first.)
For flat specimen, it is easy to define the "green" area as just a offset along the tilt-axis. Measuring "z" there can be used to adjust "z" for the red area. (Autofocus).

The practical problem arises when the sample is no longer 'flat'. If it is "pre-titled" with respect to the X/Y plane in a pre-tilt axis which is rotated with respect to the X-axis (but still lies in the X/Y) plane, then performing a tilt-series of alpha-tilts causes issues. Choosing a "focusing area" along the (now projected) tilt-axis results in a miss-measurement of Z.

So the situation is more like this:
[image]

Some colleagues argue that this can be compensated by choosing the focus area differently, but I doubt that and am seeking a convincing proof for that.

More importantly: It would be good to know where to choose the focusing area to *minimize* the error - or to make it *predictable*.

In other words: If I know the initial "pre-tilt" axis and value  (axis rotated with respect to X in the XY plane by angle and then the rotation with this axis.) and I also know the distance and orientation of the green area with respect to the red (defined in XY, i.e.  the projected system), can I then compute the difference delta-Z between the green and the red area as a function of the tomographic tilt alpha? What is the best choice for the green area to keep that error small or constant?

Comment: (Sorry for the informal naming here) So what you're assuming in the actual question is that the plane isn't parallel to the axis alpha? In that case, note that any two vectors spanning the sheet of paper and a vector along the axis alpha form a linearly independent set (you cannot use the paper basis to express an alpha vector unless alpha lies in the paper, hence is parallel to it). For that reason, the equation "point on alpha-axis"="point on paper plane" must have a unique solution (standard linear algebra), and so there cannot be a distance between the red and green areas.

Comment: @A.Sh Thanks. I think you express nicely what I intuitively think but couldn't express to my colleagues. The practical relevance of the question is the 'choosing' of a focus area for tilt-series experiments in a microscope, but I wanted to keep that out of the question. Maybe I should expand the question with the background?

Comment: Be my guest. Some background is always fun to know of. Edit: Sorry, you had apparently already done that…